# How to simultaneously display keypress for 2 separate Kivy windows

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, subprocess

I have a case where I need 2 Kivy windows each on a separate monitor to display keyboard press events simultaneously.  I have a simple toy example of the code for 'app1.py' and 'app2.py' below.

I was able to successfully use 'subprocess' and kivy.config so that when you press the 'Press to open second window' button in my main application (i.e., app1)  a second window (i.e., app2) opens on my second monitor. However, I am stuck on to how I can simultaneously display keyboard events to both application windows when the spacebar is pressed.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved, is it even possible in Kivy?

Best,
Tom

## File name: app1.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from subprocess import Popen

Window.size = (1920, 1080)
Window.borderless = True
Builder.load_string('''
<FirstWindow>:
    id: _FirstWindow
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "First Window"
            size_hint: None, None
            font_size: 50
            pos: (900,940)
        Label:
            text: _FirstWindow.key_down
            size_hint: None, None
            font_size: 30
            pos: (900,800)
        Button:
            text: "Press to open second window"
            size_hint: None, None
            font_size: 30
            size: (450, 60)
            pos: (720, 600)
            on_press: root.OpenSecondWindow()
''')

class FirstWindow(FloatLayout):
    key_down = StringProperty()  # perform button state

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FirstWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(None, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down, on_key_up=self.on_keyboard_up)

    def OpenSecondWindow(self):
        p = Popen(['python ./app2.py'], shell=True)

    def on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'spacebar':
            self.key_down = 'spacebar pressed!'

    def on_keyboard_up(self, keyboard, keycode):
        if keycode[1] == 'spacebar':
            self.key_down = ''

class App1(App):
    def build(self):
        return FirstWindow()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App1().run()
```

## File name: app2.py

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')
Config.set('graphics', 'position', 'custom')
Config.set('graphics', 'top', '-900')
Config.set('graphics', 'left', '0')
Config.set('graphics', 'borderless', '1')
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Window.size = (1920, 1080)
Window.borderless = True
Builder.load_string('''
<SecondWindow>:
    id: _SecondWindow
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Second Window"
            size_hint: None, None
            font_size: 50
            pos: (900,940)
        Label:
            text: _SecondWindow.key_down
            size_hint: None, None
            font_size: 30
            pos: (900,800)
''')

class SecondWindow(FloatLayout):
    key_down = StringProperty()  # perform button state

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(None, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down, on_key_up=self.on_keyboard_up)

    def on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'spacebar':
            self.key_down = 'spacebar pressed!'

    def on_keyboard_up(self, keyboard, keycode):
        if keycode[1] == 'spacebar':
            self.key_down = ''


class App2(App):

    def build(self):
        return SecondWindow()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App2().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

From `app1`, you can write to the `stdin` of `app2`. Here are the changes to make that happen. In your `OpenSecondWindow()` method add `stdin=PIPE` and save a reference to the `Popen` object:

```
def OpenSecondWindow(self):
    self.p = Popen(['python3 ./app2.py'], shell=True, stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

Then, in your `on_keyboard_down()` method, write to the `stdin` of `app2`:

```
def on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    if keycode[1] == 'spacebar':
        self.key_down = 'spacebar pressed!'
        self.p.stdin.write('spacebar pressed\n')
        self.p.stdin.flush()
```

And in your `app2`, you must listen for input on `stdin`. Add this code to your `SecondWindow`:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(None, self)
    self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down, on_key_up=self.on_keyboard_up)

    Thread(target=self.listen_for_input).start()

def listen_for_input(self):
    while True:
        data = input()
        self.set_label(data)

@mainthread
def set_label(self, data):
    self.ids.label.text = data
```

And the above requires an `id` in the `kv` for `app2`:

```
    Label:
        id: label
```

And you can add `stdout=PIPE` to the `Popen`, and use a similar construct to allow communication in the opposite direction.